# List / database of commonly used existing CLI executable names

Tags: data-request, software

Can someone recommend a list / database of commonly used existing CLI executable / command / alias / builtin / etc. names?

I want to write some CLI utilities, but I don’t want to have name clashes (e.g., names like `git`, `hg`, `brew`, `grep`, `Java`, `cd`, `ls`, `ll`, etc. are already commonly used).

I’m primarily interested in macOS / UNIX-like environments, but a list for Windows would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For **macOS** you can use this [list](https://ss64.com/osx/) and for **Windows** this [one](https://ss64.com/nt/). This [website](https://ss64.com/) seems to have some useful lists summarizing the CLI commands. However, there will always be extra/additional tools that can be installed/ added to the CLI such as `git`, `rsync` etc. so in -my opinion- you should always google the names you come up with, to make sure that you won't have any collusion with existing tools.

Comment: Thanks for the lists. I’m looking for something that encompasses frequently used external commands, too. But these are helpful.